# Java short circuit CompletableFuture

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

I am trying to find a way to skip CompletableFuture based on specific conditions.

For example

```
public CompletableFuture<Void> delete(Long id) {
    CompletableFuture<T> preFetchCf = get(id);
    CompletableFuture<Boolean> cf1 = execute();

    /*This is where I want different execution path, if result of this future is true go further, else do not*/

    // Execute this only if result of cf1 is true
    CompletableFuture<T> deleteCf = _delete(id);
    // Execute this only if result of cf1 is true
    CompletableFuture<T> postDeleteProcess = postDelete(id);
}
```

What is a good way to achieve this ?

Comment: if (!cf1.get()) { return ...}

Comment: That will be blocking on get().

Comment: Yes - will have to wait if the result is needed to decide what to do (or not do) next.

Comment: That defats the purpose of future chaining.

Comment: You don't really need `CompletableFutures`for the last two calls, do you? Looks like `Runnable`s will be enough?

Comment: Agreed - don't use it if you have to wait for the result.

Answer (score 2):

I will prepare a different example than the one you used in the question, because your code is not quite clear in intent from the readers perspective.

First suppose the existing of a `CompletableFuture<String>` that provides the name of a Star Wars characters.

```
CompletableFuture<String> character = CompletableFuture.completedFuture("Luke");
```

Now, imagine I have two other `CompletableFuture` that represent different paths I may want to follow depending on whether the first completable future provides a character that is a Jedi.

```
Supplier<CompletableFuture<String>> thunk1 = () -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture("This guy is a Jedi");
Supplier<CompletableFuture<String>> thunk2 = () -> CompletableFuture.completedFuture("This guy is not a Jedi");
```

Notice that I wrapped the `CompletableFuture` in a a `Supplier`, to avoid that they get eagerly evaluated (this is concept known as [thunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunk)).

Now, I go and to my asynchronous chain:

```
character.thenApply(c -> isJedi(c))
            .thenCompose(isJedi -> isJedi ? thunk1.get() : thunk2.get())
            .whenComplete((answer, error) -> System.out.println(answer));
```

The use of `thenCompose` let me choose a path based on the boolean result. There I evaluate one of the thunks and cause it to create a new `CompletableFuture` for the path I care about.

This will print to the screen `"This guys is a Jedi"`.

So, I believe what you're looking for is the `thenCompose` method.

Comment: That is not how you do asnc programming. You want to chain your futures for non blocking.

Comment: Will you'll have to call `get ` on the condition eventually if you want to evaluate it, and since you've already started the other two concurrent actions iiuc, Edwin's answer does sound like what you're looking for. Otherwise, I don't think `CompleteableFuture` is the way to go at all.

Comment: @RohitJain OK, I think I misunderstood your question. I read it again and came up with a better answer for it. I hope this is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand your objective, but why won't you just go with future chaining like you said in the comment? Something like this, just to illustrate:

```java
public class AppTest {
    @Test
    public void testCompletableFutures() {
        Integer id = (int) Math.random() * 1000;

        CompletableFuture<Void> testing = AppTest.execute()
                .thenAcceptAsync(result -> {
                    System.out.println("Result is: " + result);
                    if(result)
                        AppTest.delete(id);
                    else
                        throw new RuntimeException("Execution failed");
                })
                .thenApplyAsync(result -> AppTest.postDelete())
                .thenAcceptAsync(postDeleteResult -> {
                    if(postDeleteResult)
                        System.out.println("Post delete cleanup success");
                    else
                        throw new RuntimeException("Post delete failed");
                });
    }

    private static boolean postDelete() {
        System.out.println("Post delete cleanup");
        return Math.random() > 0.3;
    }

    private static CompletableFuture<Boolean> delete(int i) {
        System.out.println("Deleting id = " + i);
        return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(true);
    }

    private static CompletableFuture<Boolean> execute() {
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Math.random() > 0.5);
    }
}
```

Of course that doesn't make much real-life sense, but I think it works to show a concept.

If you want to skip the second call after `execute` based on the result it's clearly not possible since you need that result. The point is that it should not matter for you whether you skipped that or not since it's asynchronous, you are not blocking to wait for that result.